# jquery plug-in inner workings

Tags: jquery, function, plugins, methods

How come, if I define `jQuery.fn.my_method = function(){...}`, `jQuery.my_method` is not undefined even though I put `my_method` under the `.fn` property and not under `jQuery` directly?

I'm just curious.

```
 <script>
     jQuery.fn.my_method = function(){...};
     jQuery.my_method();//valid call even though i put my_method under .fn
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.fn` is an alias for `jQuery.prototype`, just like how `$` is an alias for `jQuery`. What you're describing is perfectly normal, you're adding a method to the prototype which then becomes available on the object.

I suggest reading up on [JavaScript prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/1156119).

Comment: Oh, i see... thanks. I know about prototypes that, if the program can't find a function directly under the object, it looks in its prototype. Also prototypes can only be defined on functions before instantiation .